# Get current Fiscal date range in python?

Tags: python, datetime, fiscal

How can i get the current fiscal date range?
Expected output :
start_date = '2022-04-01'
last_date = '2023-03-31'

Please help. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the Fiscalyear Libary?
https://pypi.org/project/fiscalyear/
There you can get Info about the Fiscal year, quarter, month and day

```
>>> e = FiscalDateTime.now()
>>> e
FiscalDateTime(2017, 4, 8, 20, 30, 31, 105323)
>>> e.fiscal_year
2017
>>> e.fiscal_quarter
3
>>> e.next_fiscal_quarter
FiscalQuarter(2017, 4)
>>> e.fiscal_month
7
>>> e.fiscal_day
190
```